# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.ParameterBlockJAI exception

Tags: java, android, servlets, jboss, jai

I am really stuck at this exception from 3 days. It was working fine but suddenly it is throwing this exception.

I am trying to upload an image for cleaning from my android device to JAVA servlet in jboss which is like this :

```
 Class Servlet extends HttpServlet{

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("You need to post an image.");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Please post an image..");
    out.flush();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();                                     // check the time, for file-naming and such
    System.out.println("Got a post - " + time);
    try{
        // get the image from the app
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
        PlanarImage image = ImageUtil.getAsImage(imageBytes);
        ois.close();
        System.out.println("Read image from stream...");

        // save a copy for inspection
        ImageUtil.saveImage(image, time + "_y");

        .......
```

And the ImageUtil.getasimage is like :

```
public static PlanarImage getAsImage(byte[] imageBytes){    
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
        bi = ImageIO.read(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(bi);                   
}
```

I am getting the following error on the line

```
  PlanarImage image = ImageUtil.getAsImage(imageBytes);
```

Error :

```
   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/VINCServer].[vinc]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet vinc threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.ParameterBlockJAI from [Module "deployment.VINCServer.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at VinCapture.doPost(VinCapture.java:41)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
```

I have also downloaded all the needed jars for the above.

```
     import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.media.jai.ParameterBlockJAI;
import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.usaa.ar.deconvolution.Restore;
import com.usaa.ar.util.ImageUtil;
```

But still no luck.Please help me as I am not able to find anything on this exception.

Comment: Not in the CLASSPATH, apparently.  What did you change since it stopped "working fine"?

Comment: nothing just ran it after 7-8 days...

Comment: Nothing?  Something changed.....downloaded the JARs and put them where?

Comment: downloaded the jars and added them to the build path by adding external jars function

Comment: They belong either in a JBOSS server directory or in your deployment WEB-INF/lib.  Which one did you choose?  What do you know about JBOSS?

Comment: I am just using JBOSS for deploying the Servlet...Do I have to create a lib folder and all the jars in it ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60648/discussion-between-user1901079-and-duffymo).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat.  Sounds like you need to learn a lot more about JBOSS, WARs, deployment, and Java EE.

Comment: I solved it by just creating a lib folder in my web-inf...thanks for your time and idea of that..